# How to create an time block entry(calendar event) for a user without overlap and race condition in Postgres RDBMS

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I have a table with from and to columns which are DateTime fields with timezone in a Postgres DB. The table also has user_id to associate this entry against a user.

I want to block a timeframe for a specific user, when it is available.

my current approach is

1. check if there is any row for the user which overlaps with the time I want to block
2. if no overlap is found, create a new row for the user with the time block specified in from and to field.

However,

there can be a race condition, when, after step 1 happen and before step 2 happen another API request could block a time overlapping.

How to,

- Avoid this scenario.
- What is the most appropriate data structure and constraint to store a range of time in Postgres, so that the constraint will ensure that no time-range exist for a user with overlap. (looking for what a composite unique index would do)
- Another database which handles this scenario better?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [exclusion constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-EXCLUSION) with a [tsrange](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html)

```
create table the_table 
( 
   id         integer primary key generated always as identity, 
   user_id    integer not null,
   timeframe  tsrange not null
);  

alter table the_table
   add constraint no_overlapping_times
   exclude using gist (user_id with =, timeframe with &&);
```

Alternatively you can create the table with two columns and create the range in the definition of the constraint:

```
create table the_table 
( 
   id         integer primary key generated always as identity, 
   user_id    integer not null,
   from_time  timestamp not null,
   to_time    timestamp not null
);  

alter table the_table
   add constraint no_overlapping_times
   exclude using gist (user_id with =, tsrange(from_time, to_time, '[)') with &&);
```

Note that the constraint needs the [btree_gist](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/btree-gin.html) extension because the `user_id` is part of the constraint (index)

You can insert new rows and deal with the error if there are overlapping ranges. Or you can test before inserting if no overlap    exists. But in any case the constraint will ensure that you can never insert such an overlapping timeframe.

Answer (score 0):

SQL requires a different thought process. SQL is declarative and set operation based not procedural. But your current approach is procedural (1st do this, then if successful do that). A set based view reduces this to just 1 step (do that if not this). Your specific case becomes: `insert a time block for the user when that time block does not overlap an existing one for the user` The following in one way to accomplish this.   
Assuming this functionality will be a common for you the below builds a SQL function to accomplish it. If the requested time frame overlaps as existing one for the user it returns, if not the it returns the inserted row. (You did not provide a table definition so I just made one up).

```
create table user_cal ( id integer generated always as identity 
                      , user_id    integer
                      , start_time timestamptz
                      , end_time   timestamptz
                      ) ;  

create or replace 
function gen_user_cal(user_id_in    user_cal.user_id%type
                     ,start_time_in user_cal.start_time%type
                     ,end_time_in   user_cal.end_time%type
                     ) 
  returns user_cal
  language sql
as $$
   insert into user_cal(user_id, start_time, end_time) 
      select user_id_in,start_time_in,end_time_in
    where not exists 
          ( select null 
              from user_cal uc
             where uc.user_id = user_id_in   
               and tstzrange(start_time_in,end_time_in,'[]') &&
                   tstzrange(uc.start_time,uc.end_time,'[]')
          )
    returning * 
$$;
```

It works by creating a TSTZRANGE ( see [range type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-BUILTIN) and [range operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-range.html)) which includes both the start time and the end time for both the requested and existing periods. Then check if they overlap (range overlap operator (&&)). See [example here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=1f7eb053c4f9f966488499c4e9c63fdd).

This drastically reduces the chance of hitting a race condition. But does not completely eliminate it. If it is still a worry see  [Transaction Isolation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/transaction-iso.html) Serializable.